# Querying a text file with a single column

Tags: apache-drill

I have a text file like below.

```
Id
126744
126745
126746
126747
126748
```

When i issue a query using apache drill ,

```
SELECT count(Id) AS COUNT from dfs.root.`/outputfiles/Job_62/riskitem/timeelement_*.txt`
```

I get a Error:

> SYSTEM ERROR: IndexOutOfBoundsException: index: 23296, length: 4 (expected: range(0, 16384))

How do I get this to work. The other CSV files have delimiter as **~** but this one does not. Count on **~** delimited files is working.

Answer (score 1):

### My observation

Drill version ==> 1.5

Useful part of plugin:

```
 "csv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "csv"
      ],
      "extractHeader": true,
      "delimiter": ","
   }
```

CSV file (drill_sample.csv)

```
Id
126744
126745
126746
126747
126748
```

Query:

```
 select count(Id) as cnt from dfs.`/home/impadmin/drill_*.csv`;
```

Output:

> 5

**Edit:** I tried with 20,000 and 5,00,000 records too. Results are as expected.

Comment: I have this "csv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "txt"
      ],
      "extractHeader": true,
      "delimiter": "~"
    },